# Solution for different Wire sizes in one circuit

Tags: current

I have two ac voltage sources in series. the connection between the sources is a 13 gauge wire. the rest of the circuit uses a 16 gauge wire. for safety i dont want to exceed 20 amps. is there a ac current limiter that i can place between the 2 voltage source?

Comment: A fuse is a normal way to protect a circuit?

Comment: A breaker will do the job, and it's resettable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 20A circuit breaker or fuse would work. Whether this would actually render your circuit safe is impossible to say without more details. You should be aware that even with a fast blow fuse, more than 20A can flow through the circuit for a short time.

Make sure that your breaker/fuse is rated for the max voltage that I can be exposed to, not just the current.

Answer (score 1):

You should hire an electrician. You are going to start a fire or get shocked. But I will try to answer your question anyway.

Fuses and circuit breakers are generally governed by some type of code. I don't know what country you are in, but in the US, the national electric code (NEC) is generally the authoritative source. So based on wire diameter and insulation temperature rating, you chose a specific size of fuse or breaker.

The purpose of circuit breakers is to prevent the wire from getting too hot and burning up the insulation or starting a fire. However, you cannot protect 16 AWG wire with a 20 Amp fuse or breaker. In fact, I am not sure if the NEC allows you to use 16 AWG wire at all. The maximum fuse or breaker for 14AWG wire is 15A.

I also want to point out that putting two AC sources in series is a tricky business. The sources need to stay synchronized somehow. This makes me wonder whether what you are doing is a good idea in the first place. I hope you know what you are doing!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you've got 15-20 in your house right now. Head on over to your nearest hardware store and pick up one of these [image] and put it in series with your circuit. Also do note that if you only had 16ga wire in your circuit, it would not be any safer than your original circuit with 16ga and 13ga wire. The wire isn't going to current limit your circuit, it'll just start a fire if you run it at too high a current for too long. So even if you're using all 16ga or all 13ga wire, if your power supply can output more current than the wire can handle, add a fuse please.

Comment: Thanks .      Is there a safe  way to  have two ac sources in series without them being in sync.?

Comment: No. If they're out of sync there's going to be large currents flowing between them because of it. You're likely to damage either the AC source or the wiring or something else if you try that.

Comment: Thanks i researched that house hold in US are single phase.  Still researching how to sync the sources.  Thanks again

Comment: Well eventually the fire will probably stop the electricity flow after the house burns down, so you could just call it a very slow blow fuse.

Comment: What are the two sources?

Comment: There is no reason large currents would flow, in theory anyway. The maximum possible voltage is still the sum of the two. But if they are out of sync, then they will at times partially cancel (destructively interfere) and at other times add up (constructively interfere). This is very unlikely to be satisfactory for any useful purpose. If the frequencies are close, and the amplitudes are close, they will nearly cancel for long periods of time, and nearly sum up for long periods of time.